# I want to execute a function before controller destruction

Tags: angularjs

In my application i have a simple angularjs controller, i want to warn the user before the destruction of my scope.
Anyone have an idea of how doing it properly ?

```
App.controller('myCtrl',["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.myVariabl = "test";
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$destroy` event:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() { ... });
```

Look it up [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), near the end, section "Events".

I doubt you can warn the user in that function though. You'd better catch the event that destroys the scope (clicking a button?), ask the user there and, if the user agrees, proceed with the destruction of the scope.

Comment: the problem is that are many button that will destroy my scope

Comment: Could you be more specific, preferably a fiddle/plunk with the problem?